# Unknown database 'my_db' , errno: 1049,

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, mysql2

I am very new with **backend** and **database**
I am using **node** ,**sequelize** and **mysql2** to connect to connect to `my_db` that I have created it through **MySQl workbench** .

this is my code

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const sequelize = require("./utils/db");

sequelize.sync().then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("runned");
  });
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
})
```

**utils/db.js**

```
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize("my_db", "root", "3132820", {
  dialect: "mysql",
  host: "localhost",
});
module.exports = sequelize;
```

**models/toto.js**

```
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = require("../utils/database");

const Todo = sequelize.define("Todo", {
    //? Model attributes
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    text: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    completed: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false,
        allowNull: true, //? default is true,
    },
});

module.exports = Todo;
```

and I get this error
[image]

and also I have **created** database in mysql
[image]
how can I **fix** this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last pic, it's not a database, it's just a connection to your mysql server, you need to create a database in your mysql server.